# Configure Cloud Role Name for Application Insights in an Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I would like to set the cloud_rolename of the telemetry sent from my Azure Function App (v2) that is sent to application insights.

The AI configuration in my host.json looks like this:

```
 "applicationInsights": {
          "sampling": {
            "isEnabled": true,
            "maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond" : 1
          }
        }
```

I have been unable to find any documentation on where to set cloud rolename in function apps. How should I go about this?

Comment: You write the function in portal or in Visual studio?

Comment: @IvanYang I use visual studio only and deploy a .net core application

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by registering a custom `TelemetryInitializer`. See here: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/759#issuecomment-426687852.

We currently set that role name in an initializer today here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights/Initializers/WebJobsRoleEnvironmentTelmetryInitializer.cs.

Can I ask what your scenario is that you'd want to override it?

Comment: I followed the link you provide, but the custom TelemetryInitializer does not take effect. I set a breakpoint there, but it does not hit.

Comment: Would you mind hopping over to that issue and posting your code? It'll be easier for us to figure out the issue that way.

Comment: Thanks @brettsam. I will give that a go in the morning. The scenario is primarily to get cleaner module names in the application insights application map when using microservices and a single AI instance. We also want to merge the staging slots as they pollute the map.

Comment: @brettsam, I uploaded my code [here](https://github.com/imeya/test/blob/master/azure-function-appinsights), if you need more info, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: @brettsam, any feedback?

Comment: @brettsam I have tried this solution, but setting the rolename this way does not change the role name of the generated AI events.

Comment: Sorry for the delay -- it looks like we've got a bug in our tooling where the build doesn't generate the correct extensions.json file anymore. I've filed an issue here and we're looking into it: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3731