# Add metadata to traces in Azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-function-app, .net-core-2.0

I have an Azure function(.NET core 2.0) that runs on each PR in an ADO repo.
I would like to add the PR-ID as metadata to each trace logged by the Azure function.
(I am viewing the logs using the `traces` table in Azure application insights instance)

The  Azure function logs traces via:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
{
  logger.LogInformation("Trace Message");
}
```

How can I add additional metadata to each trace?

Comment: How/Where is this PR id stored, in the incoming http request?

Comment: Yep. There is also other metadata in the incoming HTTP request that I would like to log.

Answer (score 4):

Yes this is possible.

**Option 1:** Using a Telemetry Initializer with the help of [AsyncLocal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1?view=netframework-4.8):

```cs
    public class CustomTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        public static AsyncLocal<string> MyValue = new AsyncLocal<string>();

        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            if (telemetry is ISupportProperties propertyItem)
            {
                propertyItem.Properties["myProp"] = MyValue.Value;
            }
        }
    }
```

You can set the value of the AsyncLocal in the function like this:

```cs
        [FunctionName("Function")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]
            HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            var name = req.Query["name"];

            CustomTelemetryInitializer.MyValue.Value = name;

            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            return new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}");
        }
```

When you run the function you can see the information in the portal:

[image]

You can find the whole code at [this repo](https://github.com/Expecho/Blog/tree/master/FunctionApp/FunctionApp)

Now, addressing your comments. Yes you need something extra. The `ITelemetryInitializer` instance needs to be registered using dependency injection. That is done in the `Startup` class as outlined in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection):

```cs
    using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

    [assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(FunctionApp.Startup))]

    namespace FunctionApp
    {
        public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
        {
            public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
            {
                builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, CustomTelemetryInitializer>();
                builder.Services.AddLogging();
            }
        }
    }
```

Once registered the Application Insights SDK will use the `CustomTelemetryInitializer`.

**Option 2**
The other option does not involve any TelemetryInitializer, but you can only add properties to the generated RequestTelemetry that is added by the Azure Function App Insights integration. This is done by making using of the fact that the current `TelemetryRequest` is stored in the `HttpContext`:

```cs
       [FunctionName("Function")]
        public static IActionResult Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]
            HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            var name = req.Query["name"];

            CustomTelemetryInitializer.MyValue.Value = name;

            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var telemetryItem = req.HttpContext.Features.Get<RequestTelemetry>();
            telemetryItem.Properties["SetInFunc"] = name;

            return new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}");
        }
```

This will show up in the portal as well:

[image]

Is it a problem that the context is added only to the Request? It might, but be aware you can query all related telemetry and know what context is involved, for example:

```
union (traces), (requests), (dependencies), (customEvents), (exceptions)
| extend itemType = iif(itemType == 'availabilityResult',itemType,iif(itemType == 'customEvent',itemType,iif(itemType == 'dependency',itemType,iif(itemType == 'pageView',itemType,iif(itemType == 'request',itemType,iif(itemType == 'trace',itemType,iif(itemType == 'exception',itemType,"")))))))
| extend prop = customDimensions.SetInFunc
| where ((itemType == 'trace' or (itemType == 'request' or (itemType == 'pageView' or (itemType == 'customEvent' or (itemType == 'exception' or (itemType == 'dependency' or itemType == 'availabilityResult')))))))
| top 101 by timestamp desc
```

will show:

[image]

All telemetry that comes from the same invocation will have the same `operation_Id`.

Comment: Thanks ! Do I need to do something extra so that `CustomTelemetryInitializer.Initialize` is invoked?

Comment: In the first answer, I see that is invoked by a combination of 
defining `public class MyStartup : IWebJobsStartup`
` and `[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(FunctionApp54.MyStartup))]`

Comment: @Nishant added a less intrusive alternative.

Answer (score 1):

This could be implemented with **ITelemetry Initializer**, you could add custom dimension to a specified telemetry like only for request.

1.Install the following nuget packages:

```
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights, version 2.11.0

Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions, version 1.0.29
```

2.The below is my test code.

```
[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(FunctionApp54.MyStartup))]
namespace FunctionApp54
{

    internal class MyTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {

            //use telemetry is RequestTelemetry to make sure only add to request
            if (telemetry != null && telemetry is RequestTelemetry && !telemetry.Context.GlobalProperties.ContainsKey("testpro"))
            {
                telemetry.Context.GlobalProperties.Add("testpro", "testvalue");
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyStartup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, MyTelemetryInitializer>();

        }
    }

    public static class Function2
    {


        [FunctionName("Function2")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            return name != null
                ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
                : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! A couple of questions:

1. What does this line do?: `[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(FunctionApp54.MyStartup))]`

2. Can `telemetry.Context.GlobalProperties.Add` be invoked only via `MyTelemetryInitializer::Initialize` ? I fear that the properties I want to log may not be available that early.

Comment: It's used to add the WebJobsStartup assembly attribute that specifies the type name used during startup. The `GlobalProperties.Add` is the method under `ITelemetry `.

Comment: And if you want to add the property in your function you could refer to this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/53332461/10383250 However this will create a new trace.

Comment: The solution you are referring to adds custom events into the app, I believe it is different that a trace. Those events cannot be easily correlated with the traces.

Comment: Seems like there is no way to add custom defined metadata to each trace that is emitted by `log.Information`

Comment: I opened an issue on Github: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1384